# NSMutable Array not updating UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios6, nsmutablearray

I m trying to update UITextview text with NSMutable array but String1 is not updating with String2, String3 and so on. Am i doing something wrong in coding.

```
Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"String1",@"String2",@"String3",@"String4", @"String5",..... nil];           

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateText)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

self.textView.text = @"String1";

- (void)updateText {
int index = [Array count];

for(int i = index; i < Array.count; i++){

self.textView.text = [Array objectAtIndex:i];
}}
```

Comment: Variable names should be lower case..

Comment: What's the point of looping and setting the label over and over? to a different value??

Comment: Your code does not make any sense to me. the code in loop will not be executed at all.

Comment: by incrementing index it will not update uitextview

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `Array` as a variable name. That is a reserved word. Also you're initializing a a standard array to an NSMutableArray. If you want a mutable copy from a standard array just do:

```
NSMutableArray *yourMutableArray = standardArray.mutableCopy;
```

or just intialize it as a mutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *yourMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"String1",@"String2",@"String3",@"String4", @"String5",..... nil];
```

Look at your updateText function above: You're starting your loop at the end of your array and your loop only goes to the end of the array. It wont even enter the loop.

Comment: When i m trying to update randamly then it works with the below code but when updating serial wise than randomly with above code doesn't work. int index = arc4random() % [myArray count];
    myTextView.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You're choosing a random number and the mod most likely wont return a valid index. I've just edited my answer to include more problems with your code above

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine(replace your updateText with this and check)

```
- (void)updateText {
   static int counter=0;
   int index = [Array count];
   counter=++counter%index;//increase the counter...but make sure that if it gets greater than the number of strings in array....it gets back to 0
   self.textView.text = [Array objectAtIndex:counter];    
}
```

Your code has some mistakes:
1)The dots in the first line must leave(i guess you know..just saying)
2)In updateText you say(i write what the computer will see....when tries to execute your code!)

```
int index = [Array count];//5 for example
for(int i = 5; i < 5; i++){
   self.textView.text = [Array objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

So the line

```
self.textView.text = [Array objectAtIndex:i];
```

never gets executed;

3)Finally even if you change the for loop to:

```
int index = [Array count];//5 for example
for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
   self.textView.text = [Array objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

What will happen is(i suppose there are 5 strings in Array for example): When the updateText runs....the for loop gets executed instantly....i becomes 2..3..4..5 very fast and the text changes from "String1" to "String2"..."String3".."String4"...and finally "String5" so fast that you see only going from "String1" to "String5"
After this...every 2 seconds.....updateText gets executed again....and the same thing happens. So what you see is.....text "changing"...from "String5"...to "String5"...so you see nothing happening!
Hope thats clear.